# how to create language selector in node

Tags: node.js, internationalization, pug

I am relatively new to node.js and am using node, express and mongoose.
I have implemented i18n module and configured
Now I need a drop down with the supported languages with flag icons and on click want to call the setLocale() but don't know how to do this
All ideas are welcome.

Also in not all the jade templates the `__('hello')` translation is picked up e.g

```
.dropdown
    button.btn.dropdown-toggle(type='button', id='dropdown1',data-toggle='dropdown')
        img(src='/img/navbar-list.png', alt='Cloud iBeacon')
    ul.dropdown-menu(role='menu',aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1")
        li(role='presentation')
            a(role='menuitem',href="/") __('home')
```

Doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

That depends on how you config i18n, if you use a cookie named 'locale' to store locale:

```
// minimal config
i18n.configure({
  locales: ['en', 'fr'],
  cookie: 'locale',
  directory: __dirname + '/locales'
});
```

// express.cookieParser then i18n.init

```
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(i18n.init);
```

then you can set locale via cookie, set this route to your app:

```
// set a cookie to requested locale
app.get('setlocale/:locale', function (req, res) {
  res.cookie('locale', req.params.locale);
  res.redirect('back');
});
```

then create menu with 2 items en, fr. (as your example, bootstrap?)

```
.dropdown
    button.btn.dropdown-toggle(type="button" data-toggle="dropdown") Dropdown
    ul.dropdown-menu
        li: a(href="/setlocale/en") en
        li: a(href="/setlocale/fr") fr
```

example here:

https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node/blob/master/examples/express-jade/express-jade.js

Comment: Thanks for this, the set locale/:locale route is called and the cookie is set however if i call this code in Jade template it still show the language that has been set as default. getLocale shows also the defaultLanguage

    p= __('Hello')
    p= getLocale()

Comment: how is your middleware order? Also check Hello in locals folder

Comment: I have no middleware setup the i18n is configured and init in express.js configuration and I want to use it in my controllers and views (Jade) can you explain what I am missing?